# JTabbedpane is not correctly created when moved to separate class

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

When intializing JTabbedpane in my main class everything works fine, but in order to don't repeat the same code over and over again I wanted to move the initialization part to separate class so I can easyli create new tabs without generating the same code again.
Unfortunately after moving the code to separate class the JTabbedpane is not created properly, because items added to list are not displayed. It looks like the JPanel is not loading as the screen under the tab is greyed (when it is working it is white).

Below is the code that works:

```
private void initialize() {
    frmLoganalyzer = new JFrame();
    frmLoganalyzer.setTitle("LogAnalyzer");
    frmLoganalyzer.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmLoganalyzer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frmLoganalyzer.setExtendedState(frmLoganalyzer.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frmLoganalyzer.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel systemLogTab = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("System Log", null, systemLogTab, null);

    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel<LogSystem>();

    systemLogTab.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    JList list = new JList(listModel);

    list.setCellRenderer(new CustomListCellRenderer());
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);

    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
    listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    listScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    systemLogTab.add(listScroller);
}
```

I tried to move it to look like this:

```
private void initialize() {     
        frmLoganalyzer = new JFrame();
        frmLoganalyzer.setTitle("LogAnalyzer");
        frmLoganalyzer.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmLoganalyzer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frmLoganalyzer.setExtendedState(frmLoganalyzer.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        frmLoganalyzer.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        TabManager tabManager = new TabManager(tabbedPane);

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel<LogSystem>();

        tabManager.addTab("System Log", null, listModel);
}
```

And in the class for initializing the tab:

```
    public void addTab(String tabName, Icon icon, DefaultListModel<LogSystem> listModel) {  
        JPanel systemLogTab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab(tabName, null, systemLogTab, null);

        systemLogTab.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JList<LogSystem> list = new JList(listModel);

        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomListCellRenderer());
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);

        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        listScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        systemLogTab.add(listScroller);
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You code does not compile, please remove the unnecessary part. Always copy-paste your code into your IDE before posting to verify that we can run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted a lot of code not relevant to the GUI and had to change the `addTab` method definition because `tabbedPane` wasn't visible. It works fine:

```
public class Example {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static void initialize() {

        JFrame frmLoganalyzer = new JFrame();
        frmLoganalyzer.setTitle("LogAnalyzer");
        frmLoganalyzer.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmLoganalyzer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        frmLoganalyzer.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel systemLogTab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("System Log", null, systemLogTab, null);

        systemLogTab.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JList list = new JList();
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        systemLogTab.add(listScroller);

        frmLoganalyzer.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void initialize2() {

        JFrame frmLoganalyzer = new JFrame();
        frmLoganalyzer.setTitle("LogAnalyzer");
        frmLoganalyzer.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmLoganalyzer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        frmLoganalyzer.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        addTab("System Log", tabbedPane);
        frmLoganalyzer.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addTab(String tabName, JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {

        JPanel systemLogTab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab(tabName, null, systemLogTab, null);
        systemLogTab.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JList list = new JList();
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        systemLogTab.add(listScroller);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        initialize(); // call initialize2() and see that it's the same
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thanks to you I have found where was my mistake. It occured that by mistake I have assigned new instance of JScrollPane deeper inside my code (unfortunately I didn't paste it here). Anyway thank you for your answer it helped me to resolve my problem!